# Optimal way to handle multiple link from url and views

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am actually creating the general structure of a "web-page" (it is just for training). In my main.html I have some link to other pages

```
    <div Id="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="{% url 'Home' %}">Home</a>
    <a href="{% url 'News' %}">News</a>
    <a href="{% url 'Contact' %}">Contact</a>
    <a href="{% url 'About' %}">About</a>
    </div>
```

My question is: Is there a way to automatize the handelling of all these links when creating a view and the urlpattern? My url.py is like this

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('main/', mainPage),
path('main/home', home, name='Home'),
path('main/news', news, name='News'),
path('main/contact', contact, name='Contact'),
path('main/about', about, name='About'),
```

]

For the moment is ok, but if one have more links it become quickly annoying. Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: I could be wrong but I do not think that is possible for many reason. You best bet in my opinion would be copy and pasting

Comment: What are the views like? Are they all the same? Are you sure you need separate URLs and views at all, rather than just capturing the slug and using it to get the relevant page from the db?

Comment: For the moment the views are all the same, just a return request with an html file nothing special on it. Example: def home(request):
    return render(request, 'mainPage/home.html').                                        
What do you mean by capturing the slug? For the moment it is super basic, I do this to learn Django, there is no db involved yet, I am actually curious about "capturing the slug and using it to get the relevant page from the db", If you could give me more information I would be grateful :)